# AWS Lambda python: .so module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regex._regex' when in subshell

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run some of my simple CI jobs (e.g: linters) into lambda functions for my python repositories.

I'm using gitlab-ci for this, and the basic architecture (not directly related to the problem but it may help the choices) is the following:

a CI jobs is defined as a set of shell commands in my case just running `black --check .`  (a python linter):
  1. the shell commands are sent to my lambda
  2. the lambda git clone the repo
  3. the lambda execute in a subprocess the commands
  4. the result is returned

so my lambda looks like this:

```
import os
import stat
import sys
import json
import subprocess
import stat
import shutil

from git import Repo


def main(event, lambda_context):
    # I've commented out, so that if you like trying to reproduce it
    # at home, you don't need the additional dependencies :) 
    #Repo.clone_from("https://example.com/the/repo.git")

    # the command sent by the CI having a shebang in it
    # the quick and dirty solution we found is to write it into 
    # a shell script and then executing said script
    script = open("/tmp/script.sh", "w")
    script.write(event["command"])
    script.close()

    st = os.stat("/tmp/script.sh")
    os.chmod("/tmp/script.sh", st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

    # the copy is just to be extra-safe
    copy_env_variables = os.environ.copy()
    # for all the binary added by the requirements.txt
    # we edit PYTHONPATH for black in the subshell to find the modules
    lambda_root_dir = os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"]
    copy_env_variables["PATH"] = copy_env_variables["PATH"] + f":{lambda_root_dir}/bin"
    copy_env_variables["PYTHONPATH"] = (
        copy_env_variables.get("PYTHONPATH", "") + ":" + lambda_root_dir
    )
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        "/tmp/script.sh",
        shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        env=copy_env_variables,
    )
    (stdout, _) = proc.communicate()

    return {"return_code": proc.returncode, "output": stdout.decode("utf-8")}
```

and the lambda is packaged with this script: (python3 is python3.7 and I'm on linux x86_64)

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t  ./
zip -r archive.zip . -x \*.pyc *.git*
```

the requirements.txt is the following:

```
gitpython
black
```

and when I execute the CI job, I got in the output of the subprocess:

```
$ black --check .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/bin/black", line 6, in <module>
    from black import patched_main
  File "/var/task/black.py", line 15, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/var/task/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File "/var/task/regex/regex.py", line 402, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/var/task/regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regex._regex'
```

The special thing about `regex._regexp` is that it's a compiled module, named `regex/_regex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` , however if i import it directly in my lambda code, it works without problem.

Is there something I'm missing about the way python deal with modules coming from .so libraries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem come from the binary having `/usr/bin/python3` in its shebang and pointing to python3.6, so python3.6 can't load `.so` compiled for python3.7

Strangely even though the Lambda was deployed with python3.7 runtime. In lambda python3.7 is located in `/var/lang/bin/python3.7` , so for the moment I have modify my CI to  symlink python3.7 in `/var/lang/bin/python3.7` so the shebang generated by `pip` is the correct one for lambda,

Comment: Can you be more specific how we should solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You package lambda on your machine. Lambda runtime uses (probably) different linux distro. You may want to spin up `amazonlinux:latest` image with Docker and package lambda from there. (You may find the steps here https://smirnov-am.github.io/ci-ci-pipeline-for-aws-lambda-python-runtime/)

Comment: Don't use `amazonlinux` images to build your lambdas. Use LambCI's `lambda` image instead: https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/